# Redirect to a resource route with parameters Laravel

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, parameters, routes

I try to redirect to a resource route with paramateres in my laravel controller

```
Redirect::route('users.show', array('user'=> $user->account_id));
```

but the parameter is never getting passed through.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how do you define your route?

Comment: when I list my routes than I get users.show and is defined as  Route::resource('users', ......)

Comment: It should work. May be you are passing null value. Check the value of $user->account_id

Comment: yes @Parth Vora the id was not generated on the flow because the create method of my eloquent model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. May be you are passing a null value.

Check the value of `$user->account_id` using `dd($user->account_id);`

Answer (score 2):

You can Try like this

```
redirect()->route('users.show', ['user'=> $user->account_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Redirect::route('users.show', ["user" => $user->account_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "return" keyword before "redirect". Try like this

```
return redirect()->route('users.show', $user->account_id);
```